# The attitude is many-to-many. My participation. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables **t_items**, **t_users**, **items_likes**.

```
create table t_items (
item_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar);

create table t_users(
user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar);

CREATE TABLE items_likes (
like_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar references t_items(item_id),
user_id varchar references t_users(user_id));

insert into t_items values('it1', 'item1');
insert into t_items values('it2', 'item2');
insert into t_items values('it3', 'item3');
insert into t_items values('it4', 'item4');
insert into t_items values('it5', 'item5');
insert into t_items values('it6', 'item6');
insert into t_items values('it7', 'item7');
insert into t_items values('it8', 'item8');
insert into t_items values('it9', 'item9');
insert into t_items values('it0', 'item0');

insert into t_users values('user1', 'name1');
insert into t_users values('user2', 'name2');
insert into t_users values('user3', 'name3');
insert into t_users values('user4', 'name4');
insert into t_users values('user5', 'name5');

insert into items_likes values('li1', 'it1', 'user1');
insert into items_likes values('li2', 'it2', 'user1');
insert into items_likes values('li3', 'it2', 'user2');
insert into items_likes values('li4', 'it3', 'user2');
insert into items_likes values('li5', 'it3', 'user3');
insert into items_likes values('li6', 'it1', 'user3');
insert into items_likes values('li7', 'it4', 'user4');
insert into items_likes values('li8', 'it2', 'user4');
insert into items_likes values('li9', 'it5', 'user5');
insert into items_likes values('li0', 'it1', 'user5');
```

I need a request that will show the user likes with the total number of likes.
Here such a request gives only the number of my likes. And I need the total number of likes.

```
select
    t_items.item_id,
    t_items.title,
  count(distinct items_likes.like_id) as likes_count
from t_items
LEFT OUTER join items_likes on t_items.item_id = items_likes.item_id and items_likes.user_id = 'user3'
where 
items_likes.user_id = 'user3'
group by t_items.item_id, items_likes.user_id;
```

I have the wrong result:

```
  item_id title likes_count
1  it1    item1     1
2  it3    item3     1
```

I need result:

```
  item_id title likes_count
1  it1    item1     3
2  it3    item3     2
```

How to find out the total number of likes I participate in?

Work example:
https://rextester.com/live/TZUAAE31639

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28347b28ae4d2dd02cf0477bfca592cc)

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    count
FROM (
    SELECT
        il.item_id,
        i.title,
        user_id,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY il.item_id)
    FROM
        items_likes il
    JOIN t_items i ON i.item_id = il.item_id
) s
WHERE user_id = 'user3'
```

The partition clusters the items and counts every of this group. This count is added as separate column to the original table.

After adding the group count the table can be filtered by the user.

Comment: @SergeyKozlov Changed to query according to your added expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    t_items.item_id,
    min(t_items.title) as title,
    count(case when item_likes.user_id = 'user3' then 1 else null end) as my_likes
    count(distinct items_likes.like_id) as total_likes
from t_items left outer join items_likes on t_items.item_id = items_likes.item_id
group by t_items.item_id, items_likes.user_id
having count(case when item_likes.user_id = 'user3' then 1 else null end) > 0;
```